# Flatten nested Ior's with scala-cats

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Working with scala-cat's [Ior](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/ior.html) data type I encountered the following problem:

```scala
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

type Locale = String
type FailureMessage = String
type Failures = NonEmptyList[FailureMessage]

private def listTranslationFiles(): IO[FailureMessage Either Array[File]] = ???

private def analyzeTranslationFiles(fs: Array[File]): Failures Ior Seq[(Locale, File)] = ???

private def readTranslations(): IO[Failures Ior Seq[(Locale, File)]] = for {
    files <- listTranslationFiles()
    fileIor = if(files.isLeft) (NonEmptyList(files.left.get, Nil): Failures).leftIor
              else files.right.get.rightIor
    // fileIor: Ior[Failures, Array[File]]
    analyzed = fileIor.bimap(identity, analyzeTranslationFiles)
    // analyzed: Ior[Failures, Ior[Failures, Seq[(Locale, File)]]]
    result = ??? //  how do I 'flatten' analyzed here?
} yield result
```

In my last step I need to convert this type:

`Ior[Failures, Ior[Failures, Seq[(Locale, File)]]]`

into:

`Ior[Failures, Seq[(Locale, File)]]`

by somehow `flatten`ing the `Ior` (I want to accumulate all left `Ior`'s into the top-level `Ior`). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can literally just replace the `???` in `result = ???` with `analyzed.flatten` in your code and it will work perfectly, thanks to the `flatten` syntax method provided by `FlatMap` and the fact that `Ior` has a `FlatMap` instance when the left side is a semigroup (as it is here).

You can do a little better than that by replacing these two lines:

```
analyzed = fileIor.bimap(identity, analyzeTranslationFiles)
result = analyzed.flatten
```

With the following:

```
result = fileIor.flatMap(analyzeTranslationFiles)
```

…since any time you're using `bimap` with `identity` on the left side, you can replace it with `map`, and any time you're using `map` and then `flatten`, you can replace both with `flatMap`.

Comment: For some reason IntelliJ told me `flatten` does not exist on `Ior` (As far as I can tell I got all the implicit imports). Your second approach works perfectly, though. Thank you very much!

Comment: I hate to tell you this but at some point you're going to have to choose between IntelliJ and idiomatic Cats-using code. :)

Comment: Yeah I already noticed that IntelliJ's letting me down more and more the deeper I dive into cats. Both the performance as well as code-completion is getting worse and worse with every new type class. :)